# CSS3 Transition Failing

Tags: html, css

I can't get transition to work on a website i'm working on. The nav menu hides and shows correctly, but it just appears instantly without tranistion. The CSS is this:

```
.nav ul li ul li {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul 
{
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

and the HTML is

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tested it in chrome, ffx, ie.

I actually got most of this code off another answer on this site, so i'm not sure what my problem is here.

I should have mentioned, I have tried opacity from other answers, but in a drop down menu, it won't work as the menu stays there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This CSS this will work fine

```
.nav ul li > ul {
   opacity:0;
    overflow:hidden;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul 
{
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    height:auto;
    opacity:1;  
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/wUabV/)**

Comment: I added height:0; to the top bit, otherwise this worked well, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The transition from `display: none` to `display: block` does not behave like you expect.

Work with `opacity` instead.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/e73px/)

Comment: The problem with this, is for a drop down menu, the menu is actually there, meaning opacity can't be used in this case

Comment: @Wayneio What about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/e73px/1 or this http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/e73px/2

Answer (score 0):

display property does not work with transitions.

what itay suggested is valid,and you can play with other properties as well (position ?)
to make the desired effect.

Comment: Couldn't understand what do you mean with the `nav`? He uses a class

Comment: huh, thats pretty weired as i looked again at his code, maybe the post was edited, i think the first part of my answer is irrelevant now, Gonna modify it .. thanks for the heads up  Itay